# Can’t get tsserver-plugins to work in Atom or VSC

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

Me and my coworkers goal is to have code completion in our Angular 2 templates like described [in this gif](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angelozerr/tsserver-plugins/master/images/Angular2Demo.gif).

Therefore we need

[tsserver-plugins](https://github.com/angelozerr/tsserver-plugins)

with

[tslint-language-service](https://github.com/angelozerr/tslint-language-service) and [@angular/language-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/language-service)

So we tried:

```
npm install tsserver-plugins -g
npm install angelozerr/tslint-language-service --save-dev
npm install @angular/language-service --save-dev
```

and we added this to our `tsconfig.json` > compilerOptions:

```
"plugins": [
    { "name": "tslint-language-service"}, 
    { "name": "@angular/language-service"}
]
```

Since i couldn’t figure out how to tell Atom’s TypeScript plugin to use `tsserver-plugins` instead of tsserver, i hacked it by renaming

`/usr/local/bin/tsserver` to

`/usr/local/bin/_tsserver`

and

`/usr/local/bin/tsserver-plugins` to

`/usr/local/bin/tsserver`

Now i thought it should work, but it didn’t.

Then i restarted Atom – nothing changed.
Then i restarted my Computer – nothing changed.

Then i installed typescript@next (2.3.0.dev...) locally and globally and repeated everything.

My coworker tried to get it to work with Visual Studio Code without success. What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At first `tsserver-plugins` needs `tsserver` and it should work with any TypeScript version. It is not a fork of tsserver.

`tsserver-plugins` wraps the `ts.createLanguageService` to load `plugins` declared in your `tsconfig.json`.

To do that that the [bin/tsserver-plugins](https://github.com/angelozerr/tsserver-plugins/blob/master/bin/tsserver-plugins) :

- loads the `typescript/lib/tsserver.js` in a string
- concat the [before-tsserver.js](https://github.com/angelozerr/tsserver-plugins/blob/master/src/before-tsserver.js) with the `typescript/lib/tsserver.js`
- run the result of concat as node module.

To retrieve `typescript/lib/tsserver.js` you have 2 strategies:

- `tsserver-plugins` is installed in the same `node_modules` than `typescript`and it get `typescript/lib/tsserver.js` with `require(typescript/lib/tsserver.js)`
- `tsserver-plugins` is NOT installed in the same `node_modules` than `typescript`, so you need to set the path of TypeScript with `--typescriptDir` parameter when you call tsserver-plugins.

For instance, if you have that:

- C:/dir1/node_modules/tsserver-plugins
- C:/dir2/node_modules/typescript

You need to execute:

```
node C:/dir1/node_modules/tsserver-plugins/bin/tsserver-plugins --typescriptDir C:/dir2/node_modules/typescript
```

And the end, the `tslint-language-service` and `@angular/language-service` needs to be hosted in the same node_modules folder than TypeScript.